# How to un-mangle terminal output

Tags: bash, shell

I have a mystery bash script. For all intents and purposes it's calling out to some third party code that I am not familiar with.

Normally, when I run a command in my shell, after it completes I can continue using my shell ordinarily -- for example, pressing my up arrow key will let me scan through the last several commands I've executed, and so on.

But when I run this mystery bash script, afterwards my terminal output gets mangled, so if I try pressing the up arrow key a few times, I see some escape codes get printed:

```
$ ./script.sh       
$ ^[OA^[OA^[OA
```

1. Are there any ways to work around this e.g. by echo-ing/print-ing out something at the end of the script in order to reset things so pressing the up-arrow key works as normal?
2. What causes this kind of behavior / what is a minimal way to reproduce it? For the curious, I encountered this error while working with a JavaScript library that does some inter-process communication using STDOUT under the hood I believe (see [here](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2927)), but it's a large library so it's tricky to debug.

Comment: Did you try running `reset`?

Comment: Is it possible it launched a new shell? I can almost reproduce the behaviour if I run `dash` from Bash. I get `^[[A` when I press Up, since Dash doesn't use `readline`. The difference in escape code (`O` vs `[`) might be just an OS-specific thing, I'm not sure. Speaking of that, what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using macOS with zsh, though coworkers using Linux distributions have also had the issue. Adding "reset" to the end of the script does work, but it clears the entire terminal screen and takes about a second on my machine to do so, which doesn't seem ideal

Comment: I guess that something run by `script.sh` is modifying the terminal settings.  A possible workaround is to use the [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) utility to run it connected to a pseudoterminal, so the shell's terminal isn't affected.  One way to do it with the Linux version of `script` is `script -q -c ./script.sh /dev/null`.  I'm not sure if `script` is available on macOS by default.  If it is available, it may use this (untested) alternative syntax: `script -q /dev/null ./script.sh`.

Comment: `stty sane` might work if `reset` is too much

Comment: Answers to [How to reset a broken TTY?](https://superuser.com/q/640338/1081707) may be useful.